# Provide additional root to 'Bundle React Native code and images' Xcode build step

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to integrate React Native into our existing iOS application. I have loosely followed [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html).

I say loosely because I do not want to install React Native into my top level project folder. We have an existing directory structure and I need to be able to reference and use React Native from not only my top level app project, but also some of our native libraries, so I want to install React Native into a more generic location in our existing directory structure. Here is the current directory structure I am trying to make work:

```
ios
|
+-- myapp
|  |
|  +-- myapp.xcodeproj
|  \-- ReactComponent
|     |
|     \-- index.ios.js
|
+-- libinternal
|  |
|  \-- libbusinesslogic
|     |
|     \-- libbusinesslogic.xcodeproj
|
+-- libexternal
|  |
|  \-- ReactNative
|     |
|     \-- node_modules
|        |
|        \-- react-native
```

I want to be able to reference the same React Native install from both `myapp` and `libbusinesslogic` Xcode projects. That is why I have installed React Native into the more generic location: `libexternal/ReactNative`.

Unfortunately, React Native does not seem to be very friendly to this sort of 'non-standard' installation. Right now I am trying to figure out how to integrate the 'Bundle React Native code and images' build step into my project. I created a brand new project using `react-native init` and copied the script build step from that into the `myapp` project. It started out like this:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh
```

That won't work for my project because I installed React Native in a different location, so I changed it to this:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
../libexternal/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh
```

When I build `myapp`, the script fails with this error:

> uncaught error Error: NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/jboehle/Desktop/projects/ios/libexternal/ReactNative"]

There does not appear to be a way to pass an additional root to the `react-native-xcode.sh` script.

After spending some time Googling, it seems like there may be some way to do this with a custom `rn-cli.config.js` file, but I have been unable to get it to work.

Is there a way to make this work with my existing directory structure?

**EDIT:** I also ran across [this issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3984), which seems like the exact same question I am asking. It's marked closed but I don't see any real resolution to the issue. The original author of that ticket posted a fix for running the packager with a different root, but *not* the bundler script with a different root.